# CMDeviceMotion stops updating when the app is brought back to foreground from background

Tags: ios

I start device motion updates in the foreground. When I put the app to background by locking the phone, I continue to get updates but when I unlock my phone, device motion stops updating. Accelerometer,gyroscope and location updates are working fine both in background and when I bring it back to foreground.

I am using CMMotionManager for getting accelerometer,gyroscope and device motion.
I am reading the pitch, roll and yaw values from Device Motion.

Answer (score -1):

Try SOMotionDetector. This is very helpful library. This will work on both cases foreground & background. 
https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/SOMotionDetector

Comment: "answer" should actually contain an answer.[Click Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/296892)

Comment: I din't get @SahilKapoor. Please Explain.

Comment: Click link in my previous comment and it will help you understand how to answer properly.

Comment: I need to get pitch,roll and yaw updates. Not just activity detection.